# Linux to Windows - can't connect to device in LAN

Tags: linux, windows, networking, lan

I've got a C# program running on Windows desktop that's broadcasting on UDP, and I've got a Java program running on Raspian Buster that's listening to the broadcasts. Both devices are connected via ethernet cable to the same switch. However, the Java client doesn't receive the broadcasts.

All of that worked fine until I moved and changed my network setup.

What I tried:

Desktop's IP is 192.168.1.22
Raspberry's IP is 192.168.1.25

On Windows, calling `arp -a` in cmd shows me the Raspberry:

> 192.168.1.25          b8-27-eb-db-16-f0     dynamic

On Raspberry, calling `arp -a` shows me the desktop:

> desktop-so5t7k8-1.home (192.168.1.22) at 70:85:c0:7f:4f [ether] on eth0

Pinging Raspberry from Desktop works fine (no packets lost, time<1ms)
**However, pinging Desktop from Raspberry doesn't work - 100% packet loss**

I realize that might be caused by a miriad of possible problems, but I don't know where to start. How do I get around to debugging this?

Comment: Try to temporarily disable the Windows firewall.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get around to debugging this?

There are two things to try, in any order:

1. Firewall configuration. Windows comes with a firewall that's configured to block "new" inbound packets – it prompts you *once* for every new program that attempts to listen for packets, but you might very well end up with java.exe blocked if you've closed the dialog in a hurry.

   Run `wf.msc` to open the Windows Firewall configuration tool, navigate to "Inbound" rules, and look for any rule that explicitly blocks the executable. If found, either change it to an "allow" rule, *or* delete it and manually add a port-based rule. (For example, add a rule to allow receiving UDP to port 23456.)

   Keep in mind that some antivirus programs come with their own firewall and disable the one included with Windows.
2. Packet capture. Install Wireshark on the machine that's supposed to receive packets, point it at your network interface, use it to verify whether the system overall receives the UDP packets you're looking for. If they show up in a packet capture but not in the program – it's usually a firewall issue. If they *don't* show in a packet capture – that's some kind of a network issue (e.g. the switch or Wi-Fi access point blocking broadcasts).